# raspberry pi files regularly sync with owncloud-client-cmd

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, synchronization, client-server, owncloud

I made cloud server a raspberry pi with owncloud server. And I installed owncloud-client-cmd other raspberry pi. How to regularly sync client to raspberry pi with commandline?(I have three raspberry pi client)  Please advise me

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You could edit your crontab file on your RPi with:

```
pico /etc/crontab
```

and at the bottom add a line like:

```
*/5 * * * * pi /usr/bin/owncloudcmd /path/to/owncloud/directory https://your.server/path --user your-owncloud-user --password your-owncloud-password
```

Then you should reload your cron daemon with:

```
/etc/init.d/cron reload
```

Comment: Hi Patrizio, I set in /etc/crontab ***/5 * * * * pi /usr/bin/owncloudcmd /home/pi/ownCloudBox2 http://192.168.0.50/owncloud/remote.php/webdav --user admin --password 123456** but didn't sync folders. I can see and change the folders on browser, windows desktop client.

Comment: I run with cmdline **sudo owncloudcmd /home/pi/ownCloudBox2  http://192.168.0.50/owncloud/remote.php/webdav** then I wrote username and password but I get this error                                       **03-01 12:14:15:235 Strange: User is empty!
03-01 12:14:15:235 Error: User is emty!
03-01 12:14:15:237 QNetworkReplyImplPrivate::error: Internal problem, this method must only be called once.
03-01 12:14:15:241 Strange: User is empty!
03-01 12:14:15:279 QWidget: Cannot create a QWidget when no GUI is being used**

Answer (score 0):

I found different a path for sync server-client on raspberry pi.
[It is working perfectly](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/7.0/user_manual/files/files.html)
https://doc.owncloud.org/server/7.0/user_manual/files/files.html